# How can I reuse javascript file-size-check validating function?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

There are two file inputs in my form. (#file1 and #file2)

```
<input type="file" name="file1" required="required" id="file1"
                    onchange="size1Check();"
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif"
                    required="required" />

 <input type="file" name="file2"
                    required="required" id="file2" onchange="size2Check();"
                    accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif"
                    required="required" />
```

and I made this file-size checking functions!

```
function size1Check(){

    var size = document.getElementById("file1").files[0].size;
    console.log("size : " + size);

    if(size > 1024 * 1024 * 2){

        alert('your file size : ' + (Math.round(size / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100) + 'MB');
        $("input[id=file1]").val("");
    }

    else return; 
}



    function size2Check(){
    
        var size2 = document.getElementById("file2").files[0].size;
        console.log("size2 : " + size2);
    
        if (size2 > 1024 * 1024 * 2){
            alert('your file size : ' + (Math.round(size2 / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100) + 'MB');
            $("input[id=file2]").val("");
        }
    
        else return;
}
```

as you can see, size1Check and size2Check functions are almost the same one, except for the id(file1 and file2)
how can i reuse the function to make the code simpler?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Pass a parameter in function and access that in function

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline handlers - they're pretty universally considered to be quite poor practice in modern web development. You can iterate over each `<input>` you want a handler for and call `addEventListener` on each:

```js
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')) {
  input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const size = input.files[0].size;
    console.log("size : " + size);
    if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
      alert('your file size : ' + (Math.round(size / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100) + 'MB');
      input.value = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file1" required="required" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" required="required" />

<input type="file" name="file2" required="required" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" required="required" />
```

or if you prefer to create only a single handler function, you could

```js
const handler = (e) => {
  const input = e.target;
  const size = input.files[0].size;
  console.log("size : " + size);
  if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
    alert('your file size : ' + (Math.round(size / 1024 / 1024 * 100) / 100) + 'MB');
    input.value = '';
  }
};
for (const input of document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')) {
  input.addEventListener('change', handler);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file1" required="required" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" required="required" />

<input type="file" name="file2" required="required" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" required="required" />
```

(change the CSS selector `input[type="file"]` as needed to add the handler to only the `<input`s you want to add the handler to)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by passing the value as an argument to the function `sizeCheck()`, further defining it as another argument, but for `document.getElementById()`. Like this:

```
function sizeCheck(element) {
    var size = document.getElementById(element).files[0].size;
    ...
}
```

The argument is **element**.

But in the html of each tag, inside event `onchange`, you must specify the current element with the **id** property to identify the current element. Like this:

```
onchange="sizeCheck(this.id);
```

And remove the duplicate `required="required"` attribute in each `input` tag.

This is full snippet:

```js
function sizeCheck(element) {
    var size = document.getElementById(element).files[0].size;
    console.log("size : " + size);

    if (size > 1024 * 1024 * 2) {
        alert("your file size : " + Math.round((size / 1024 / 1024) * 100) / 100 + "MB");
        $("input[id=file1]").val("");
    } else return;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file1" required="required" id="file1" onchange="sizeCheck(this.id);" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" />
<input type="file" name="file2" required="required" id="file2" onchange="sizeCheck(this.id);" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/gif" />
```